# How to dynamically add operation to stream in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, java-8, java-stream

I have following code:

```
private List<EmployeeDto> doTransformation(List<Employee> employees, Optional<Predicate<Employee>> filter, Integer limit, Integer offset) {

    Stream<Employee> stream = filter.isPresent() ? employees.stream().filter( filter.get() ) : employees.stream();
    // do offset sql based for stream //not working
    if ( offset != null ) {
       stream.skip( offset );
    }    
    // do limit sql based for stream //not working
    if ( limit != null ) {
        stream.limit( limit );
    }
    return stream
        .map( employee -> /*do some mapping to EmployeeDto*/ )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
```

In this part of code:

1. Applying filter to stream, if filter exists;
2. Want to do some **offset** and **limit** for this stream but this **not working** because of "A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once".
3. Do mapping to dto object and collect as list.

How to do stream operations **skip()** and **limit()** in other way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `stream = stream.skip( offset );` Both [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) and [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) returns a modified stream. They don't change the original stream object. **Read the documentation**. The javadoc of both says: *Returns the **new** stream*.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Here's an [example](https://ideone.com/PEcMki) with `filter`, `offset` and `limit` which works fine. Please post the reproducing MCVE as well as the complete exception you're getting.

Comment: What problem are you facing? I have run your example with skip and limit and it is working fine.

Comment: @lexicore That code of yours is not dynamically applying `skip` and `filter` only when needed, so how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @Andreas How is "dynamic application" relevant to the reported problem? If `skip` or `filter` are not applied, there is no problem. If they are applied, then how is it different from my code?

Comment: @Andreas If you think otherwise, please modify my code to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AmitBera java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: @Andreas 1. I know and asking how to do it in another way. 2. Why not dynamically? If limit or offset is not null then stream should do additional operation. Maybe if speak in context, it is not because new stream should be created but in scope of architecture it is dynamical

Comment: @lexicore this example isn't good for me because if limit is null I should put there some value. But I just realized that I can put list.size() value if limit is null. Let me try :)

Comment: @badCoder I'm just saying I could not reproduce the problem so I'm inclined to close the question. Please post a MCVE, a working reproducing example we could try.

Comment: @badCoder You need to handle it manually as Java does not provide any API to test if a stream is closed.

Comment: @lexicore The entire point of this question is that `skip` and `limit` should only be applied **sometimes**, aka *dynamically*. When you make the calls *statically*, like you did, it means that they are *always* called. You are not in any way addressing the problem posted in the question. And I don't need to modify your code, because I've already modified the code in the question to make it work (see [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448900/how-to-dynamically-add-operation-to-stream-in-java?noredirect=1#comment85899886_49448900)).

Comment: @badCoder Sorry, I don't understand what you were trying to say to me with [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448900/how-to-dynamically-add-operation-to-stream-in-java?noredirect=1#comment85900557_49448900). The solution is in the [very first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448900/how-to-dynamically-add-operation-to-stream-in-java?noredirect=1#comment85899886_49448900). Did you try it?

Comment: As for *"A stream should be operated on only once"*, you're only operating on it one. By "operated on", they mean that you can execute a *terminal* operation only once. Calling `stream = stream.skip( offset );` does not operate on the stream, it simply adds another step to the stream chain. The stream is "operated on" when you call `collect(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I made this little example, maybe it is useful in your case?

```
Integer offset = null;
Integer limit = 2;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("batman", "one", "seven", "woohooo", "awesomeness"));
List<Integer> lengths = list.stream()
    .skip(offset != null ? offset : 0)
    .limit(limit != null ? limit : Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .map(String::length) //as an example of mapping
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

lengths.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `limit(0)` is not unlimited.

Comment: @Andreas change made

Comment: @JackFlamp thanks Jack but it is not good for me, Integer.MAX_VALUE bad practise and let's imagine that there is more than few billion records :)

Comment: @badCoder Since you are using Integer for limit you can't go higher anyway. Why is it bad practice?

Comment: @JackFlamp make sense.